# Responsive menu not working on mobile devices - blogger

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

My menu is not working on mobile devices. I'm using blogger to host my custom domain. It is working fine on desktop version but not on mobile devices. How and where should I insert the following code?

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
        var cssmenu = $(this),
            settings = $.extend({
                format: "dropdown",
                sticky: false
            }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).find(".button").on('click', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
                var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
                if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
                    mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
                } else {
                    mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
                    if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                        mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                    }
                }
            });
            cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
            multiTg = function() {
                cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
                cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                    if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                        $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
                    }
                });
            };
            if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
            else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
            if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
            resizeFix = function() {
                var mediasize = 767;
                if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').show();
                }
                if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
                }
            };
            resizeFix();
            return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
            format: "multitoggle"
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
nav{position:fixed;width:100%;margin:0;padding: 0;}
#cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu {margin: 0;padding:0; border:0;list-style:none;line-height:1;display:block;position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu > ul:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:none}
#cssmenu{font-family:sans-serif;background:#000}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{padding:17px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-weight:800;}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul li.active a{color:#000;}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover {background:#FFB82B!important;-webkit-transition:background .3s ease;-ms-transition:background .3s ease;transition:background .3s ease;}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a{padding-right:40px}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {position:absolute;top:22px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#fff;content:''}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#fff;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:23px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul{position:absolute;left:-9999px;}
#cssmenu ul ul li{height:0;-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;background:#333;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul{left:auto;}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul ul{margin-left:100%;top:0;}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);padding:11px 15px;width:170px;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-weight:700;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a{border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover{color:#000;}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:16px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#fff;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:13px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#fff;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:17px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{background:rgba(255,184,43,0.9);} /*hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh*/           
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover{background:rgba(255,184,43,0.9);}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover{background:rgba(255,184,43,0.8);}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:1px solid #333}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a{border-top:1px solid #333}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
nav{width:100%;}
#cssmenu{width:100%}
#cssmenu ul{width:100%;display:none}
#cssmenu ul li{width:100%;border-top:1px solid #444}
#cssmenu ul li:hover{background:rgba(255,184,43,0.9);}
#cssmenu ul ul li,#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:auto}
#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu ul ul li a{width:100%;border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{padding-left:25px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{background:#333!important;}    
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{background:rgba(255,184,43,0.7)!important}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a{padding-left:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{color:#fff;background:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a{color:#000}
#cssmenu ul ul,#cssmenu ul ul ul{position:relative;left:0;width:100%;margin:0;text-align:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before{display:none}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:block;padding:23px;color:#fff;font-size:12px;font-weight:700}
.button{width:55px;height:46px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;cursor:pointer;z-index: 12399994;}
.button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:20px;display:block;height:4px;width:20px;border-top:2px solid #ffffff;border-bottom:2px solid #ffffff;content:''}
.button:before{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;position:absolute;top:16px;right:20px;display:block;height:2px;width:20px;background:#fff;content:''}
.button.menu-opened:after{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;top:23px;border:0;height:2px;width:19px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
.button.menu-opened:before{top:23px;background:#fff;width:19px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}
#cssmenu .submenu-button{position:absolute;z-index:99;right:0;top:0;display:block;border-left:1px solid #444;height:46px;width:46px;cursor:pointer}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened{background:#262626}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button{height:34px;width:34px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:19px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#fff;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after{top:15px;right:13px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after{background:#fff}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:22px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#fff;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before{top:12px;right:16px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before{display:none}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:none}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a{border-top:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id='cssmenu'>
    <div id="head-mobile"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>TELANGANA</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>ANDHRA PRADESH</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i desperately need this.  kindly help me!!!

Comment: Fixed code formatting, grammar fixes, added tags